# Taming a high request count web using a service worker

Tags: javascript, requirejs, service-worker, http2

I have a very specific problem. We have a significantly bloated, large application for library and student management written using dynamically loaded requirejs modules. Our GUI is composed of multiple components that all load as they become required. One panel loads a button, field, table, then table loads other components like buttons, fields, maybe even other tables and so on.
The end result is that a dashboard and details pages or different listings in this SPA sometimes have 300-500 requests, depending on complexity of any particular view configuration, which is ally dynamic.
With every millisecond of latency we have when using it, and sometimes it's quite large like 200-500 ms, the loading of such SPA on navigation, especially on first load, can take even minutes.

My job is to fix it and what i did so far is I moved it all to a HTTP2 server to streamline some loading and wrote a simple Service Worker to manually preload the application to cache so, even across sessions, we have cache and just intercept all GET requests for .js, .css and .jpg files. The application files itself don't change very often anyway.

But, one problem we still have. Even with request intercept and much faster per-file responses (since we don't check with server at all), the sequential nature of RequireJS is daunting. It's simply sequentially requesting files as it loads module by module. That still takes a lot of time and since we have some HEAD requests here and there, which always go to server, this also gets in the way since those block every next request until resolved.

Is there a way to preload all the available cached files up front, so to even skip having the service worker wait for each fetch event and respond to each of those sequentially? Starting all requests at the same time would help a lot.

Comment: I think you don't need a service worker for that... Can you use `Cache-Control: max-age=<seconds>`? this will cache the assets client site and you don't hit the server as well.

Comment: Can you use webpack or similar?

Comment: @RolandStarke unfortunately, it hits the server that way, because for every request a browser needs to check with the server if there is an update and get a "go ahead with cache" from the server. Not much on fast connection, but in rural areas with high latency, even that takes a toll. The service worker intercepts and returns files immediately. But, 500 files take time anyway when in a succession. Starting all at once or some kind of preloading would be great.

Comment: @RomanCortes It was built with a highly customized npm build process so can not use webpack. Need to use what I have.

Comment: So, what about if you try to require in the main file as many modules as possible, so it would attempt to download in parallel, and then it will have them cached... I hope

Comment: @Anthony "because for every request a browser needs to check with the server if there is an update" reread about that. that is not true with `Cache-Control: max-age=<seconds>`

Comment: @RolandStarke We still have significantly better response times with sw than browser auto cache, but I'll check into it, thank you.

Comment: @RolandStarke Seems that we still have significantly better performance with a service worker than with classic cache.

Comment: i can't imagine a big difference. Could you show the network tab in the developer tools?

Comment: It's worth noting that when a SW caches a JS file in Chrome, it will cache the parsed representation of the JS. This should lead to some performance advantages over traditional browser caching of JS, in which the network can be avoided, but the JS still needs to be read from disk and re-parsed each time.